# Customize Salesforce session timeout popup page

Tags: session, timeout

Is it possible to customize salesforce session timeout page to include time remaining to continue session and add a logo by nullifying the salesforce default logo. I have searched on this topic but did not find anything related to it. Please let me know if anyone has an idea on this.